In asp.net core how to register both saml and cookie authentication method and use either one as per user's attribute
I have added a new field "EnternalUser" in aspnetuser table.  This field will have the value either 0 or 1.  if it is set as 1 then I would like to use cookie authentication, otherwise I would like to use saml authentication.
I would like to how to register these two authentications method in program.cs with the default being set as cookie authentication.  In Login.cs , if the user's 'ExternalUser' property happen to have value as 0 then I would like to invoke Saml authentication.
